# Issue with Chrome download - bug/hack ??? got version 86 instead of 93

Tags: linux, google-chrome, debian, security, updates

I am confused by a recent Chrome update.  Chrome warned me that it could not update itself and said I should do it manually. So I thought I should do what it said and update Chrome.. so I clicked the link in the Chrome browser to get to the Chrome download page and got the .deb package. Everything looked fine until I did a command line install when I saw it.

```
user@debian-linux-pc:~$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb 
[sudo] password for user: 
dpkg: warning: downgrading google-chrome-stable from 91.0.4472.101-1 to 86.0.4240.75-1
```

so it looks like I am now installing an older version of Chrome, which just is wrong. So what happened.

So I have Firefox as well, so I didn't want to open the older version of Chrome, so I opened Firefox and used it to get the latest chrome.deb file... so when I downloaded I saw that

```
ls -lt *.deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 82931984 Sep  2 23:32 google-chrome-stable_current_amd64(1).deb
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 71150488 Oct  5  2020 google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

so the new version is from today and the previous version I downloaded is nearly a year old...

so I then deleted the old version and `mv`ed the new .deb file to `google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` and reinstalled from the latest version and got

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 285742 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (93.0.4577.63-1) over (86.0.4240.75-1) ...
Setting up google-chrome-stable (93.0.4577.63-1) ...
```

so all looks good now and I go into Chrome, check the history, and try to find if it is a spoofed site that gave the older version when I downloaded with Chrome and I can only see websites that end in google.com

Does anyone know what is happening? Does this make sense? Should I be worried? It just feels like either (1) Chrome was pointing to the wrong place to update or (2) something malicious was trying to make me install an old (unsecured) version of chrome.

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Ramhound - yes - I could see that from the `ls -lt` command -- just wondering why I got that download when I downloaded it today from google.com..

Comment: @Ramhound - ah ok... I see now.... sorry sometimes when I download a file (or maybe when I rsynced files) I get a new file, but with its original creation date - or maybe it is when I expand a .zip file...   So I found the issue was that I was looking in the wrong place for the download and **you are correct** that I have got confused and found an old file rather than the .deb file I have just downloaded... ... and I was confused because firefox and chrome download to different directories

Comment: @Ramhound, really appreciate the help, was going mad trying to figure out what the issue was, many thanks for the help. .... so If you want to put that as an answer I can accept it - or maybe I should just delete the question - what do you think?

Comment: @Ramhound - slightly more complicated... I downloaded the new version and it went into a different directory because firefox and chrome download to different directories... so I had just downloaded from chrome, but found a version that I had downloaded a year ago with firefox because I was looking in the wrong directory... I then downloaded the new version with firefox which got the (1) extension... etc. - but your comments led me to the solution- so many thanks :-)

Comment: Please don't edit the question to add an answer, or put 'solved' in the title. Stack Exchange doesn't work that way. If you have an answer, it goes in the answer space. Then you can mark it as 'accepted' using the check mark.

Comment: @Tetsujin - ok fair enough, but the problem is that I cannot accept the answer I have put in for 2 days and this problem is fixed - it was trivial - I don't want to waste people's time by looking through the details of a solved problem - maybe I should just delete the question, but @ Ramhound suggested that I should answer it rather than delete it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the new version with chrome and it went into a different directory than the one I expected because of Firefox and Chrome download to different directories.

So I had just downloaded from Chrome but found a version that I had downloaded a year ago with firefox because I was looking in the wrong directory.  I then downloaded the new version with firefox which got the (1) extension but was the correct current version.

I then found the correct current version had indeed been downloaded the first time with Chrome, just ended up in a different directory (or a different folder).